# Visual Studio Project within the solution not loading (load failed) and appearing with errors

Tags: visual-studio, project

I have cloned code from our company ADO area (someone else's code files) and when loading it in visual studio 2022 I cannot load one of the projects in the solution (unloaded). I get the following two errors:

Error 1: The Web Application Project is configured to use IIS.  Could not find the server on the local machine. Make sure the local IIS server has been configured to support secure communications.

Error 2: A project with that name is already opened in the solution.

My colleague who originally wrote the code can clone the code and doesn't get the same issue.

I am also getting a lot of dbl files and debug files automatically populating in the changes and every time I make a change to the code it generates more changes for these kinds of files which is quite hard to then see in git changes what changes are mine and what have been autogenerated.

Can anyone help?! I am new to the Development world, and this is really stumping me!

I have tried going into the user file and setting use IISExpress to false. Was expecting that to resolve the error 1 message but it hasn't.

I have tried putting a gitignore file into my project but it isn't ignoring the files in the changes being auto generated in git changes.